# How can I speed up query like SELECT id FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE "Someting%" ORDER BY col2 LIMIT 10

Tags: mysql

I'm using MariaDB 10.1

How can I speed up query like `SELECT id FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE "Someting%" ORDER BY col2 LIMIT 10`

Because of `%` in `LIKE` statement I can't use composite key (col1, col2), so it lead to filesort. However, the number of result is quite large to perform filesort.

Is there any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE 'Someting%'
ORDER BY col2
LIMIT 10;
```

There are two choices for optimization.  For the `WHERE` clause, you can use an index on `table(col1)` -- although adding `col2` and `id` covers all the columns in the query with some improvement.

This works because there is no wildcard at the beginning of the `LIKE` string.  If you are looking for words, then you might want to consider a full text index.

The second choice is more arcane but it might be helpful if lots and lots of rows match the `where` clause:

```
select id
from (select id
      from table
      order by col2
     ) t
where col1 like 'Something%'
limit 10;
```

Along with an index on `table(col2, id, col1)`.  I'm not 100% sure this will work, but the idea is to encourage the engine to do a full scan of the index, testing the `where` clause on each entry.

Answer (score -1):

Put **INDEX** on `col1`.

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.

Syntax to add **INDEX**:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `col1` (`col1`);
```